# Изменения значения X-XSS-Protection header в jboss 5.1

Tags: jboss

Я использую Jboss 5.1 и по дефолту значения заголовка X-XSS-Protection
Я хочу изменить значение и делаю это так в web.xml :

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>CommonHeadersFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
         org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>X-Powered-By</param-name>
            <param-value>Servlet 2.5; JBoss-5.0/JBossWeb-2.1</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>X-XSS-Protection</param-name>
            <param-value>0</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CommonHeadersFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

После рестарта сервера значение по умолчанию не поменялось и осталось прежним. 
Как мне сделать изменения, чтобы поменять значение заголовка на 0.